# Add to irregular cell selection with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add irregular cells into a selection via VBA.

In the code below, there are some cells marked with 1's in column E on a sheet.
It's supposed to loop through that column and make a a selection string, then use that string to select the corresponding cells in column A, as a single selection block.

My problem is that the output string will only work if I dump it to a spare cell, then manually copy it into VBA.

Any thoughts appreciated!

```
Sub AddToSelection()

Dim B As Worksheet, SelectString As String, RX As String
Set B = ActiveSheet

For C = 1 To 20
    If B.Cells(C, 5) = 1 Then
    
        If RX = "" Then
            RX = """" & "A" & B.Cells(C, 5).Row
            Else
            RX = RX & "," & "A" & B.Cells(C, 5).Row
            End If
        End If
    Next C

RX = RX & """"

Range(RX).Select 'does NOT work



''''BUT

B.Cells(1, 10) = RX ' I dump RX into a cell

SelectString = "A3,A5,A8" ' this copied manually from cell above, so is exactly RX

Range(SelectString).Select 'now it works


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are off (shouldn't be adding `""""` to the beginning and end), but it's much better to use `Union` here:

```
For C = 1 To 20
    If B.Cells(C, 5) = 1 Then
        Dim rng As Range
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = B.Cells(C, "A")  ' or B.Range("A" & C)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, B.Cells(C, "A"))
        End If
    End If
Next C

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Select
End If
```